# MongoDB PHP Date

Tags: mongodb, codeigniter, date

In my database I have a document like this.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5465508f453c9446d228b225"),
"category" : "animals",
"lastLocation" : "Wilpattu",
"lastSeenDate" : "2013-05-26",
"company" : "53fd9a3204ac58132377f807"
}
```

I want to check if the given date is in between two date ranges. I am using Codeigniter for front end development. In the model class I have written,

```
     $connection =$this->Dbconnect->GetMongoCon();
     $database  = $connection->etsp;
     $collection = $database->trackedObjects;


    $start = $AnimalArray['fyear']. '-'.$AnimalArray['fmonth'].'-'.$AnimalArray['fday'];

    $end = $AnimalArray['lyear']. '-'.$AnimalArray['lmonth'].'-'.$AnimalArray['lday'];



    $searchCriteria = array(
   'company' => $AnimalArray["Company"],
    'lastSeenDate' =>array('$gt' => $start1, '$lte' => $end1)

   );

  $ReturnAnimalArray=$collection->find($searchCriteria);
```

But I can't query the date. From internet I have tried converting date into mongodb format.

```
  $start1 = new MongoDate(strtotime(date($start )));
  $end1 = new MongoDate(strtotime(date($end)));
```

But that also did not work. Any hint will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lastSeenDate is not MongodbDate format, may be you should like do this:

```
$js = "function() {
    return this.lastSeenDate > '2013-02-18' && this.lastSeenDate <= '2014-09-28';
}";

$collection->find(array('$where' => $js));
```

Comment: Hey can you please tell me how to pass a variable instead of '2013-02-08'?

Comment: $js is string variable, you can replace date with your setting

Comment: Is it within the function? eg: return this.lastSeenDate > $start

Comment: like this: str_replace("%date%", $start, "function () {return this.lastSeenDate > '%date%' }");

Comment: Now I can pass variables. Really appreciate your help.